# Is there a way to change hooks dynamically in Kedro?

Tags: kedro

I know I can add any CLI option via kedro_cli.py.
but I can't find out how to change what hooks are loaded dynamically.

I'm using [kedro-mlflow](https://kedro-mlflow.readthedocs.io/), which features are provided via hooks.
And sometimes I don't want to log MLFlow temporarily.

If it's possible, please show me an example of ProjectContext code.

Answer (score 0):

If the hooks have an entry-point as described in https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/05_plugins.html#hooks , you would be able to disable it by specifying in `.kedro.yml` https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/04_hooks.html#disable-auto-registered-plugins-hooks but you might have to ask the maintainer of kedro-mlflow plugin to add auto-registration first.